# MySQL / RegEXP / Split First Name and Last Name

Tags: mysql, regex, mysql-workbench

Using MySQl Workbench, I am trying create a query where I take a column that has first and last name, and split it into FirstName and LastName USING REGEXP.

For example, if I have a cell from a column that has "Tom Della 'Angelo", I would like the FirstName query results to have "Tom" and the LastName query results to have "Della 'Angelo".

I have tried:

```
SELECT "Tom Della 'Angelo"
REGEXP ".*(?:\n|$)";
```

But this does not return much, other than a number.

Please do not recommend simply creating two columns, one for first and one for second. Please do not recommend something that doesn't use REGEXP.

Comment: You can't win.  Some people have 2-word first names; some have 2-word last names.  Some have lots of middle names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysql> set @name = 'Tom Della ''Angelo';

mysql> select regexp_substr(@name, '^[[:alpha:]]+') as FirstName,
              regexp_replace(@name, '^[[:alpha:]]+ ', '') as LastName;
+-----------+---------------+
| FirstName | LastName      |
+-----------+---------------+
| Tom       | Della 'Angelo |
+-----------+---------------+
```

These [regexp functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html) require MySQL 8.0.

Comment: Thank you! Can this be generalized to a full column? In other words, if I had a full titled EmployeeName with a list of employees, would I simply replace the single name with the column name?

Comment: I just tried it out using a full column, and it seems to work. thank you!